# Como posso comparar duas listbox items um por um

Tags: vb.net

Estou a desenvolver um novo *software* que verifica as assinaturas digitais e tenho 2 `ListBox`. A primeira com as *hash* que se obtem dos ficheiros contidos no directorio escolhido pelo usuario, a segunda com as assinaturas `MD5` de virus conhecidos eu preciso de comparar item por item se na `listbox4.items.contain(listbox5.items)`.

Como posso fazer esse `loop` e comparar com todas as chaves existentes
um por um?

Desde ja agradeço.

Eu ja procurei no Google mas nao encontrei nada que me possa ajudar.

Este e o meu código:

```
Private Sub comparador_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comparador.Tick
    For Each hash1 As String In ListBox4.Items
        ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.SelectedIndex + 1
        For Each hash2 As String In ListBox5.Items
            ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.SelectedIndex + 1
            If ListBox4.Items.Contains(ListBox5.SelectedItem) Then
                MsgBox("Virus Encontrado Em:" & ListBox4.SelectedItem)
            Else

            End If
            If (ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.Items.Count - 1) Then
                Return
            End If
            If (ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.Items.Count - 1) Then
                Return
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Depois de fazer algumas tentativas 
acabei por modificar um pouco do meu codigo inicial
para este:
Comparator e um timer

```
    Private Sub comparador_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comparador.Tick
    ListBox4.SelectedIndex = 0
    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0
    'ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.SelectedIndex + 1
    For Each hashf As String In ListBox5.Items


        If ListBox4.SelectedItem.ToString = ListBox5.SelectedItem.ToString 
Then

            MsgBox("Virus Encontrado Em:" & ListBox4.SelectedItem)
        Else
            ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.SelectedIndex + 1
        End If
        ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.SelectedIndex + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

erro
A lista a qual este enumerador está vinculado foi modificada. Um enumerador só pode ser usado se a lista não mudar.
De facto depois de tentar varias coisas encontrei uma solucao

```
Private Sub comparador_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comparador.Tick
    TextBox3.Text = ListBox5.Items.Count
    Dim counter As Integer 'new!

    'ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.SelectedIndex + 1
    For Each hashf As String In ListBox5.Items.ToString
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.SelectedIndex + 1
        counter += 1 'new
        ProgressBar1.Value = (counter * 100) / ListBox5.Items.Count 'new
        If (ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.Items.Count - 1) Then

            ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0
            ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox4.SelectedIndex + 1
        End If
        ListBox4.SelectedIndex = 0
        If ListBox4.SelectedItem.ToString = ListBox5.SelectedItem.ToString Then
            MsgBox("Virus Encontrado Em:" & ListBox4.SelectedItem)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os elementos na `ListBox` forem do tipo `string`, então o código abaixo resolve o problema de forma simples (**necessário importar `System.Linq`**):

```
Dim listHash = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList()
Dim listVirus = ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList()
Dim listUnion = listHash.Intersect(listVirus).ToList()
Dim strVirusFound As String = String.Empty

For Each strVirus In listUnion
    strVirusFound += string.Format("Virus encontrado em: {0}{1}", strVirus, Environment.NewLine)
Next

MsgBox(strVirusFound)
```

Comment: tentei o seu codigo mas me da erro na linha strVirusFound += $

Comment: o erro e no caracter $

Comment: de facto sao uma  lista de hash md5

Comment: Se não estou em erro para utilizar o `$` terá de ter a .NET Framework 4.5.2 no mínimo. Vou editar a resposta com uma solução mais abrangente.